# jQuery select "not this and not everything in this"

Tags: jquery

I got a plugin

```
$.fn.dropDown = function(options){
    this.each(function(){
        var $this= $(this);
        $(document).click(function(e){
            if($(e.target).not($this) && $(e.target).not($this).find('*')){
                // do stuff
            }
        }); 

    });
}
```

I want to select "not this and not everything in this" ,so far, that doesn't work.

Comment: So to clarify:  you want someone to initiate your plugin from one element, and then if any other element (that isn't the initializing element or a descendent of it) is clicked, then you hide your menu.  Is that right?

Comment: @JacobM I edited the question, it's clearer I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var that = this;
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if( e.target != that && !$.contains(that, e.target) ) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) doesn't take elements, it takes selectors. Also, even if that did work, you don't want to check whether `$this`'s parent has the element as a descendant, you want to check whether `$this` has the element as a descendant.